# Android- face Recognition using openCV?

Tags: android, opencv, authentication, face-recognition

In my application im going to implement face Recognition login... so i go with the openCV library for Recognize face... please help me to do this with sample code and tutorials....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my colleagues and I did some investigation on face recognition last year, and these are some of ours considerations about using integrated recognition tools vs JavaCV (the Java bindings for OpenCV):

Please check below tutorials

1. [Face Detection on Andriod Part-I](http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/01/25/about-face-detection-on-android-part-1/) ( [Wayback link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120418110445/http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/01/25/about-face-detection-on-android-part-1) )
2. [Face Detection on Andriod Part-II](http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/02/07/about-face-detection-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-1/) ( [Wayback link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120418105847/http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/02/07/about-face-detection-on-android-%E2%80%93-part-1) )

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for ur answer... actually i want to do this in android(java)... pls help me to solve this..

Comment: This blog looks to be offline :-(

Comment: your mention links are dead.

Comment: Face Detection != Face Recognition

Answer (score 0):

you can use NDK for using C/C++ OpenCV API

[docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html)
[beginner tutorial](http://niksonpaul.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/face-detection-using-opencv-c/)

```
void DetectMyFace ()
{
    // image structure in opencv
    IplImage *inImg = 0;
    // face detector classifer 
    CvHaarClassifierCascade *clCascade = 0;
    CvMemStorage *mStorage = 0;
    CvSeq *faceRectSeq;

    inImg = cvLoadImage("2.jpg");

    mStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    clCascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *)cvLoad("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml", 0, 0, 0);

    if ( !inImg || !mStorage || !clCascade ) 
    {
        printf("Initilization error : %s" , (!inImg)? "cant load image" : (!clCascade)? 
            "cant load haar cascade" : 
            "unable to locate memory storage");

        return;
    }

    faceRectSeq = cvHaarDetectObjects(inImg,clCascade,mStorage,
        1.2,
        3,
        CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
        cvSize(25,25));


    const char *winName = "Display Face";
    cvNamedWindow(winName,CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  

    for ( int i = 0; i < (faceRectSeq ? faceRectSeq -> total:0); i++ )
    {

        CvRect *r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faceRectSeq,i);
        CvPoint p1 = { r->x, r->y };
        CvPoint p2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height };

        cvRectangle(inImg,p1,p2,CV_RGB(0,255,0),1,4,0);     
    }

    cvShowImage(winName, inImg);
    cvWaitKey(0);   

    cvDestroyWindow(winName);

    // release the variables 
    cvReleaseImage(&inImg);
    if(clCascade) cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&clCascade);
    if(mStorage)  cvReleaseMemStorage(&mStorage);
}
```

Comment: thaks a lot for ur answer..this is c++... but i want in android(java)... pls help to solve this

Comment: `javacv is a wrapper for opencv. but u can use Android NDK for using C/c++ api of opencv

Answer (score -1):

I have already made an Android app for Face Recognition using OpenCV. You can check it out: https://github.com/yaylas/AndroidFaceRecognizer